# How can I check if an object exists at a specific position in unity C#?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

In this case I am looking to full an empty area with an object but I do not want to place an object there if the area is not empty.
This is specifically talking about a cube so I am not sure if the checkSphere() works.
I am a beginner and I had a lot of trouble finding an answer to this question so although I know it is probably online I had trouble finding something that explained the code in a way I understood and even finding that code.

Comment: Please explain your question some more.

Comment: Nitpick: A vector is a direction (without a starting position), I'm guessing you mean "at a specific position"

Comment: Does your GameObject have a Rigidbody component?

Answer (score 11):

Try using [Physics.OverlapSphere](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics.OverlapSphere.html). You can define a sphere at a Vector3 point you'd like to check for ((2, 4, 0) for example). You can give it a low radius (or maybe even 0, but you'd have to check that, I'm not 100% sure if it works).

It returns an array of all colliders that are touching or are inside of the sphere. Just check if the array is empty (or the length is 0) and if it is, nothing is touching it.

You could use it like this:

```
Collider[] intersecting = Physics.OverlapSphere(new Vector3(2, 4, 0), 0.01f);
if (intersecting.Length == 0) {
    //code to run if nothing is intersecting as the length is 0
} else {
    //code to run if something is intersecting it
}
```

or, of course, you could do this:

```
Collider[] intersecting = Physics.OverlapSphere(new Vector3(2, 4, 0), 0.01);
if (intersecting.Length != 0) {
    //code to run if intersecting
}
```

Hope this helps!

EDIT: Here's a function that just returns true if a point intersects with a collider.

```
bool isObjectHere(Vector3 position)
{
    Collider[] intersecting = Physics.OverlapSphere(position, 0.01f);
    if (intersecting.Length == 0)
    {
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thankyou! I thought I understood this however I recieved an error message that said "The ! operator cannot be applied to operand or type 'int'."

Comment: Ah my bad, you need to put !(intersecting.Length == 0) instead of just !intersecting.Length == 0

Comment: Why not just `return intersecting.Length != 0;`? There's no need for the branching (Also `intersecting.Length != 0` is pretty much always more readable than `!(intersecting.Length == 0)`)

Comment: @UnholySheep this is true, but I wanted to keep it simple and understandable for someone who might not be very experienced with programming. I also decided to branch instead of just returning the boolean expression because it was the same template as the previous examples I provided. But yeah- you're right.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

First collect all GameObjects in the scene

```
GameObject[] allObjects = UnityEngine.Object.FindObjectsOfType<GameObject>() ;
```

Later you can iterate all over those gameObjects to check the distance between their position and your PositionToMatch, which should be a Vector3 with the coordinates you want to check if there is anything there already

```
foreach(object go in allObjects)
{
    float dist = Vector3.Distance(PositionToMatch, go.transform.position);
    if(dist <...)
        //Here what you need
}
```

[Vector3.Distance](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.Distance.html) will return the distance. You can there set the limit considering the size (radius or diameter) of the of the GameObjects

Answer (score -1):

you can use .contains() to check if the object exists and in that case, get the position. I would need to see the code to be more accurate

Comment: Vectors do not havea  `contains()` method and neither does the Unity transform hierarchy.